# How to use Logarithm in the Sieving step of Quadratic Sieve technique

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, logarithm

I am working on a program to factor large semi-prime numbers. I am using the simple Quadratic Sieve technique. My program works well but lot slower because during the sieving process (when I was looking for B-Smooth numbers), I used division process (division method of Java "BigInteger" class). I heard that using logarithm instead of division can make it much faster. Now I know how logarithm works but I don't understand how can I fit the log operator instead of division because, in the sieving process where I need to divide the number to find it's all the prime factors.

Here is an example:

N=15347, number to be factored.
rootN = Ceil(sqrt(N)) = 124, factor base {2, 17, 23, 29}

Q(x) = (124+x)^2 - N

Now, for some x we need to find Q(x) that are completely factored over the factor base:

Q(0) = (124+0)^2 - N = 29 = 2^0 + 17^0 + 23^0 + 29^1 : B-Smooth number

Q(1) = (124+1)^2 - N = 278 = NOT completely factored over the factor base.

Q(2) = (124+2)^2 - N = 529 = 2^0 + 17^0 + 23^2 + 29^0 : B-Smooth number

Q(3) = (124+3)^2 - N = 782 = 2^1 + 17^1 + 23^1 + 29^0 : B-Smooth number

and so on,

So, to determine B-Smooth number, we need to try to divide the Q(x) with all the primes of the factor base and with their maximum possible exponent. I also used the Tonelli–Shanks algorithm to speed up finding B-Smooth numbers. Still I need the mod and division process to determine whether Q(x) is a B-Smooth or not.

Now I don't understand how can I use logarithm to avoid division that can help finding B-smooth numbers quickly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithms of your factor base primes 2, 17, 23 and 29 are 0.7, 2.8, 3.1 and 3.4. The sums of the factor base primes in your four Q are Q(0) = 3.4, Q(1) = 0.7, Q(2) = 6.2 and Q(3) = 6.6. If you set a limit that all Q with a log-sum greater than 3 are "probably smooth", then you will factor Q(0), Q(2) and Q(3) by trial division over the factor base and confirm that all three are indeed smooth (note that 529 = 23 * 23 is smooth over your factor base, even though you stated it is not).

Comment: Thank you so much, I modified my question according to your statement. I do not understand this line "The sums of the factor base primes in your four Q are Q(0) = 3.4, Q(1) = 0.7, Q(2) = 6.2 and Q(3) = 6.6." when you will use logarithm, you shouldn't have this information, Other than finding Q(x), somehow they use some sort of addition of the log values of the primes and get the anti-log to get Q(x).

Comment: The sieve sums the logarithms. After you complete the sieve, you scan for log-sums that exceed your threshhold. No anti-log required. I have code in Python if that would help you.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain with a small example or you can generate an example with your program that can help to understand the steps. A smooth number is a combination of all the primes (from factor base) with exponents starts from zero to some integer. I don’t need any code. Thanks though.

Comment: See [my blog](https://programmingpraxis.com/2013/03/19/quadratic-sieve/). There is a complete worked example on the second page of the blog entry.

Comment: Oh, that's your blog! I read that earlier before I submitted my question here. It does not contain the information I am looking for. Anyway, thank you for all the responses.

Comment: What else do you need?